# Repetition of Hashem sefatai on Friday night

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader, leil-shabbat, chazarat-hashatz

I've been thinking about lately whether should the prayer leader [repeat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93909/15256) ה' שפתי תפתח on Friday nights as in the [morning](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30083/15256) or the [afternoon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22502/15256)? My gut feeling is that he shouldn't, because it's not a proper repetition, but ברכה אחת מעין שבע, though I couldn't find yet sources for my claim.

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative, but if no sources mention it and no siddur prints it, then that might be all there is to it